# Get Customers List who have not ordered a particular kind of product

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, exists

It is in SQL Server 2008 R2.

We have 3 products, Orders and Customers:
P1
P2
P3

We'd like to know Customers who ordered P1 and P2 BUT NOT P3.  We don't want to get Customers who ordered all 3 kinds of products.  I don't know how to write that query.  Could you please 
advise me?  Thanks.

We have only 2 tables.  Orders and Customers.  Products Name are fixed.

Comment: Do you want to include the schema?  Or are we to guess?

Comment: Yes, please add in the definitions of these tables - in a preformatted section in the question, rather than as a comment.

Comment: maybe if you try you will know how to do it next time...show us what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Customer TABLE ( ID int, Name nvarchar(20) )
DECLARE @Order TABLE ( CustomerID int, Product nvarchar(2) )

INSERT INTO @Customer VALUES ( 1, 'Dave' )
INSERT INTO @Customer VALUES ( 2, 'Another Dave' )

INSERT INTO @Order VALUES ( 1, 'P1' )
INSERT INTO @Order VALUES ( 1, 'P2' )
INSERT INTO @Order VALUES ( 2, 'P1' )
INSERT INTO @Order VALUES ( 2, 'P2' )
INSERT INTO @Order VALUES ( 2, 'P3' )

SELECT          a.Name
FROM            @Customer a
INNER JOIN      @Order b ON ( b.CustomerID = a.ID AND b.Product = 'P1' )
INNER JOIN      @Order c ON ( c.CustomerID = a.ID AND c.Product = 'P2' )
LEFT OUTER JOIN @Order d ON ( d.CustomerID = a.ID AND d.Product = 'P3' )
WHERE           d.CustomerID IS NULL
GROUP BY        a.Name
```

Comment: Hard to scale to more items in the list.  So, good specific solution, not so good general solution

Answer (score 2):

Having been forced to guess the schema, and assume that a customer can order the same product multiple times, you can use something like this...

```
WITH
  Products (
    productID,
    inclusive
  )
AS
(
            SELECT 'P1', 1
  UNION ALL SELECT 'P2', 1
  UNION ALL SELECT 'P3', 0
)

SELECT
  customerID
FROM
  Orders
INNER JOIN
  Products
    ON Orders.ProductID = Products.ProductID
GROUP BY
  customerID
HAVING
  COUNT(distinct Orders.ProductID) = (SELECT SUM(inclusive) FROM Products)
  AND MIN(Products.inclusive)      = 1
```

First, the join filters everything own to just Orders including ANY of `P1`, `P2` or `P3`.

The GROUP BY makes these into groups of orders, one group for each customer.

The first HAVING clause looks at all the orders that are in that list.  It counts how many *different* products there are in that sub-set.  It checks how many *inclusive* products are in the Product list we're searching for.  It stipulates that these two figures must be the same.
*[In this example; they must have ordered exactly two different products.]*

The second HAVING clause checks if *any* of those products has `inclusive = 0`.
*[No product ordered by the customer may appear in the exclusion list.]*

**EDIT:** This is an alternative, that some people seem to prefer, but I think that it is less performant (in cases where the Orders table is of any significant size).

```
SELECT
  customerID
FROM
  Orders
WHERE
  ProductID in ('P1', 'P2')
GROUP BY
  customerID
HAVING
  COUNT(distinct ProductID) = 2
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                    FROM Orders AS lookup
                   WHERE CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
                     AND ProductID IN ('P3')
                 )
```

Comment: I think you meant `COUNT(distinct Orders.ProductID) >= (SELECT SUM(inclusive) FROM Products)`, i.e. `>=` instead of `=`, because, if a customer ordered `P1, P2, P4`, s/he should still be included in the output (or should they not?).

Comment: @AndriyM - Nope; should have been an `INNER JOIN`. `'P4'` then becomes excluded from the `COUNT()`. Must have been sleeping when I wrote `LEFT` :)

Comment: You are right. With my guess, a customer with `P1, P4, P5` would be (incorrectly) included too.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that Orders contains customerID and ProductId columns

```
select disrinct(customerID) from Orders
```

gives you all the customers that placed orders

```
select customerID, COUNT(distinct(productID))
from Orders
where productID in ('P1', 'P2') 
      and customerid not in (select customerID
from Orders
where productID in ('P3'))
group by customerID
having COUNT(distinct(productID))>1
```

gives you all the customers that placed orders with product P1 and P2 but not P3

Comment: `where productID in ('P1', 'P2') and productID not in ('P3')
` this will not work (not my down vote BTW). this will only show customers that ordered p1 OR p2 with no regard to p3.  when the row's productID='p1' it will not be 'p3' so it will be included in the result set even if another p3 row exists for that customer.  This will even return customers that only ordered a p1 and not a p2.  Remember, a WHERE looks at values of each row independently.

Comment: god you are right! I missed that. Just provided another solution that may be helpfull

Comment: @Diego - This returns a customer even if they've only ordered *one* of `P1` or `P2`, but the OP requires that a customer is returned *only* if they've ordered *both*.

Comment: sorry lads, its Friday 5 o'clock. I edited again. Solution is not good but so aren't the table's structure

Answer (score 0):

```
select CustomerId
from 
(
   select o.*,
     (case when productid = <product1> then 1 else 0 end) as has_p1,
     (case when productid = <product2> then 1 else 0 end) as has_p2,
     (case when productid = <product3> then 1 else 0 end) as has_p3
   from Orders o
) o
group by CustomerId
having max(has_p1) = 1 
  and max(has_p2) = 1 
  and max(has_p3) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select CustomerId
from 
(
   select o.*,
     (case when productid = <product1> then 1 else 0 end) as has_p1,
     (case when productid = <product2> then 1 else 0 end) as has_p2,
     (case when productid = <product3> then 1 else 0 end) as has_p3
   from Orders o
) o
group by CustomerId
having max(has_p1) = 1
```